Optoisolator for vintage digital current loop serial interface
I'm designing an adapter for a vintage 20mA current loop interface, transmitting serial at 2400 baud.  It's for Digital Equipment computers from the 1970s and 1980s, for a museum.  We don't need to a general solution, just one for this particular board: a DL11-A Asynchronous Serial Line Interface.  Our primary goal is of course to protect the museum pieces, which are from about 1978 onwards.
Solution
My idea is to use a simple 4N35 (datasheet) optoisolator circuit, with current limit resistor, for both input and output, with complete separation of power supplies.  EDIT to add: the cable is at most 20 or 30 cm, more likely 5 cm.
The question: Do I need anything more sophisticated?
See below for details of what we're interfacing to and my simulations.

Circuits we're interfacing to
The input and output circuits are as follows

The input comes in at labels K (+5V) and S (-15V) and comes out at H which feeds a 7413 Schmitt gate with 10K pullup at E.

The output is a PNP pull-up to +5V on AA and -15V on KK.

A D664 diode is apparently like a 1N3606 or 1N4153 (datasheet)

6534D transistor is like MPS6534 (datasheet)



Edited from DEC manufacturing drawing microfiche, PDF page 9

Own work
Simulations
I wasn't sure how to simulate these exactly (especially the optocouplers), but nevertheless this is what I tried.  In the input it looks like R102 can be anywhere from about 1K to 5K and still get good TTL levels at E.  In the output, I selected R201 as 1K to get about 10 mA across D201.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

simulate this circuit

Looks fine to me. I would put a Zener between the C and E of the phototransistor. The transistor would be bypassed when the open circuit voltage reaches the Zener voltage, or when the lines are reversed.
For maximum flexibility, I would put the LED and the phototransistor inside of a rectifier bridge. That's the retro equivalent of MDIX in Ethernet :)
The rectifier diodes can also be small Schottkys.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Many thanks.  Re zener: you mean K to C, A to E, with voltage say 30 V?  To protect the phototransistor?  And ditto the diode bridges, just to protect the optoisolator?  We're not worried about the optos, happy to replace them if we make a mistake anywhere!  I understand your D5=my U201-LED, your Q1=my U101-TR (actually NPN).

The diode bridges do protect against reverse polarity, but really they just make polarity immaterial. It's much nicer to the user when they can have more trust in an interface without worrying "did we cross some wires?". I think in a museum setting this sort of over-the-top design would prove useful. I'm adding the Zener to the schematic to make things clear.

Thanks, very helpful.  I edited q to explain wires are very short, likely to be 5 cm.  Your Q1 is still confusing me as it's PNP, is that just oversight? 4N35 transistor is of course NPN.
